# php form sending to handler

Tags: javascript, php, html

I did an assignment and ended up with this correct code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Assignment 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var imageURLs = [
       "p1.jpg"
     , "p2.jpg"
     , "p3.jpg"
     , "p4.jpg"
  ];
  function getImageTag() {
    var img = '<img src=\"';
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
    img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
    img += '\" alt=\"Some alt text\"/>';
    return img;
  }
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").on("click", function(event) {
        var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        alert("X Coordinate: " + x + " Y Coordinate: " + y);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(getImageTag());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

so now the next assignment says this: Your task is to add some validation to task 1B, by creating two PHP scripts.

The first PHP script that will create an HTML document that contains an img tag that is randomly selected. The HTML document will contain a form that will be used to store and send data (the click co-ordinates) to the second (handler) script.

The second PHP script is the handler that will check the submitted coordinates with the answer.  If the click is within 10 pixels of the answer, show the user a congratulations message, otherwise compute how far they were off from the answer.  You should also display the number of seconds it took for the user to send their answer.

Hint: The first script needs to send data to the second script, namely the current timestamp and a value that represents which image is being presented to the user.  The first script can send this data to the second script by using hidden input fields.

and is followed by this:

```html
Image and Answer Data

$puzzles = array ( 
    array( 'src' => "http://307.myweb.cs.uwindsor.ca/samples/wheres_waldo/pics/p2.jpg",
           'x' => 235,
           'y' => 389),
    array( 'src' => "http://307.myweb.cs.uwindsor.ca/samples/wheres_waldo/pics/p3.jpg",
           'x' => 437,
           'y' => 221),
    array( 'src' => "http://307.myweb.cs.uwindsor.ca/samples/wheres_waldo/pics/p4.jpg",
           'x' => 469,
           'y' => 110),
 );
```

I have no idea that they are even asking of me and am very confused, if anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think they are asking:

Script 1- show a random image, and when user clicks on an image, send the coordinates and the time it took since the puzzle started. The hint is to use form fields. So you need to create a form with hidden input fields. When user clicks on an image, set the values of these fields (time, coordinates, image name,etc.) and submit the form. Form needs to be handled by script two.

Script 2- decide if user should be shown win, lose or try again message, and relay this reply to the user.